# How do you find a developer of an app that hasn't been updated?

Tags: ios, ios-appstore

I purchased a scripture app for $15 several years ago.  It is the best I have ever used.

When my iPhone screen went black I had to replace my phone. The app did not reload.  I assume it is because the developer has not updated it.

I want to contact the developer and get it updated or purchase it.  There is no trace of it on my phone.  How do I find the contact information for the developer?  This app looks likes gold plates with a black background.

Comment: Though this has 2 answers already accurately giving the answer to your question as asked, I suspect it's a bit more of an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377) What you actually would like to know is "How to get the app back if it is no longer on the App Store"… this is not so easy.

Answer (score 1):

Open your App Store purchase list and find the app on that list. From there you can find the developer information and try to download it again (or see why it disappeared).

Answer (score 1):

Look in the AppStore app.

At the top right there is an icon representing yourself - which you can set so you might recognise it easily.

Press that to go to your account then choose Purchased and then My Purchases to see all the apps you have bought

Search for your app and you will get to the App's page.

That should have details of the developer etc.

But I expect they have stopped responding. However their might be enough information to search the web for their current whereabouts.

Comment: I would very much suspect that if the app is no longer on the App Store for re-delivery after a restore, then it won't appear in your history either.

Comment: @Tetsujin oh yes I expect the developer has disappeared especially as $15 is an expensive app.